# Is it possible to have more than one parse client configured in a single app?

Tags: c#, parse-platform

So I have a few different parse servers setup.
One server is just to capture error logs from various applications (I have a LOT out there) in nice uniformed database.

So I might have a specific standalone data migration tool that if it encounters an error, will write out the exception into this Error_log parse table/class. No problem there.

But, if I have an app that uses a Parse Database for itself, I have not been able to figure out how to let it work on it's own parse server configuration for it's own stuff, but write out error logs to this other Parse server instance.

Yes...  I could go through the trouble of writing out something via the REST api just for writing out logs,but I am I trying to avoid that and stick with native parse APIs for the particular platform I am on because of the benefits that the APIs give over REST (like save eventually for the none .NET stuff).

EDIT

Some clarification was requested so here I go...

On the app side of things (c# for this example but the same holds true for iOS etc)… I do the usual initialization of the Parse client as such …

```
                ParseClient.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration
                {
                    ApplicationId =  "MyAppID",
                    WindowsKey = "MyDotNetKey",
                    Server = "www.myparseserver.com/app1"
                });
```

So for all calls to save a parse object go through that parse client connection

But what I need to do would be something like this ….

```
//Main App cloud database
                ParseClient1.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration
                {
                    ApplicationId =  "MyAppID",
                    WindowsKey = "MyDotNetKey",
                    Server = "www.myparseserver.com/app1"
                });

                ParseClient2.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration
                {
                    ApplicationId =  "MyAppID",
                    WindowsKey = "MyDotNetKey",
                    Server = "www.myparseserver.com/errorcollection"
                });

try{
                ParseConfig config = null;
                config = await ParseConfig.GetAsync().ParseClient1;
} catch (Exception ex){
   ParseObject MyError = new ParseObject("Error_Log");

   MyError["Application"] = "My First App-App2";
   MyError["Error"] = ex.message;
   await MyError.Save().ParseClient2;

}
```

Yes - this is all fake code... my point is I want to be able to have multiple ParseClient instances in one app.

Now... I can simply write a routine that writes out errors that resets the ParseClient.Initialization to the error parse server instance and then redo it back to the original (primary app data) instance when it's done... but that is just asking for trouble in a multi threaded environment and will cause conflicts if some other thread in the app goes to write out parse data right at the moment the error method resets the init.

If ParseClient were IDisposable I could probably do that using :

```
ParseClient ParseErrorServer = new ParseClient();
ParseErrorServer.ApplicationId = "hmmm";
ParseErrorServer.WindwosKey= "hmmm";
ParseErrorServer.Server= "www.hmmm.com/errorcollection";

using ParseErrorServer {

   //Do The Work

}
```

Is that clear as mud yet? ;P

Comment: Hi David.  Your question probably could use an [edit] with specific details about your explicit issue.  Can you show a [mcve] of what you're working with so far, what's unclear, and where you're trying to improve?  As it stands, this is a bit too broad and could involve a lot of opinionated answers.

Comment: I would recommend looking [here](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/15) though, as it **seems** to discuss what you're asking about.  If that helps you explain your issue in any way.

Comment: Hey @gravitymixes... I did take a look at that post. It deals with multiple instances at the server side... I was rather looking todo multiple client connections to different parse servers at the app side of things.

Comment: Or to simply... here's an example... Read data from one parse server and write to another parse server asynchronously in an app.

Comment: Come on... no takers? No one knows how/if this can be done?

Comment: @DavidBrewster please take a look at my answer about multiple instances on the client SDKs. If it answers your question it would be helpful if you could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Without alteration I believe none of the Parse SDKs have the ability to initialise multiple instances.

In the iOS SDK for example, is possible to make a new instance (say with a different server url) upon restarting the app but you cannot have multiple. There has also been discussion on the iOS SDK about being able to [change the configuration without restart](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/1209) but no one has implemented this yet.

We would happily review a PR for this, however it would require a major and complex overhaul as you would have to manage cache, users etc across multiple instances.